# Using python to create a random password generator

Tags: python, random, passwords

```
import string

def generate_password(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return password

# Set the desired length for the password
password_length = 12  # Change this to your desired password length

# Generate and print a random password
generated_password = generate_password("password_length")
print("Generated Password:", generated_password)
```

I am new to python, this is a code for a random possword generator and it is not working. Pls help

Comment: "it is not working" is not a useful description of the problem. Please edit your question to include all details of what "not working" really means.

Answer (score 0):

Your password generator code is almost correct, but couple of things:

- The `random.choice` function is used in your code, but the random module is not imported.
- In the line where you call `generate_password`, you're passing the string `"password_length"` instead of the variable `password_length`. This results in a TypeError, as your function expects an integer but receives a string.

try this:

```py
import string
import random  # Import the random module

def generate_password(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return password

# Set the desired length for the password
password_length = 12  # Change this to your desired password length

# Generate and print a random password
generated_password = generate_password(password_length)  # Pass the integer variable, not a string
print("Generated Password:", generated_password)
```